# How to set Live Frame on Camera Capturing Image in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

[image]

I have to set the live frames on camera like above pic. But my `setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);` `getWidth();` `getHeight();` `Camera.PictureCallback` etc are deprecated. Anyone know the code to achieve the above?

I used

```
public class CameraOverview1 extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
private Camera camera = null;
private SurfaceView cameraSurfaceView = null;
private SurfaceHolder cameraSurfaceHolder = null;
private boolean previewing = false;
private Display display = null;
private static int wid = 0, hgt = 0;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
private View cameraViewControl = null;
private LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = null;
private Button btnCapture = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
wid = display.getWidth();
hgt = display.getHeight();

getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

setContentView(R.layout.cameraoverlay1);

cameraSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.cameraSurfaceView);
cameraSurfaceHolder = cameraSurfaceView.getHolder();
cameraSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
cameraSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

cameraViewControl = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cambutton, null);     
this.addContentView(cameraViewControl, layoutParamsControl);
btnCapture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{   
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.takePicture(cameraShutterCallback, 
                cameraPictureCallbackRaw,
                cameraPictureCallbackJpeg);
    }
});
} 
ShutterCallback cameraShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() 
{  
@Override
public void onShutter() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
}
};
PictureCallback cameraPictureCallbackRaw = new PictureCallback()
{  
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
}
};
PictureCallback cameraPictureCallbackJpeg = new PictureCallback() 
{  
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
    Bitmap cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    wid = cameraBitmap.getWidth();
    hgt = cameraBitmap.getHeight();

    Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(wid, hgt, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newImage);

    canvas.drawBitmap(cameraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);

    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable
            (R.drawable.frame1);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, wid, hgt);
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    File storagePath = new File(Environment.
            getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyCameraApp/"); 
    storagePath.mkdirs(); 

    File myImage = new File(storagePath,
            Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

    try
    {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myImage);
        newImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);


        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Log.d("In Saving File", e + "");    
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.d("In Saving File", e + "");
    }

    camera.startPreview();

    drawable = null;

    newImage.recycle();
    newImage = null;

    cameraBitmap.recycle();
    cameraBitmap = null;
}
};
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, 
    int format, int width, int height)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

if(previewing)
{
    camera.stopPreview();
    previewing = false;
}
if (camera != null){
    try 
    {
camera.setPreviewDisplay(cameraSurfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
        previewing = true;
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try
{
    camera = Camera.open();
}
catch(RuntimeException e)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device camera is not working properly, please try after sometime.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
camera.stopPreview();
camera.release();
camera = null;
previewing = false;
}}
```

Actually, pretty much everything is deprecated. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean FPS or total frame?

Comment: I'm building an app like hoarding photo frames. Look at the above pic.

Comment: So you need a double preview front and back camera?..

Comment: Guess so. Do you know the code(or any links to websites)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this sample [android-Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

I've applied some change and this is result:

**Camera2BasicFragmentFront.java**

[Source](http://pastebin.com/Krsgyd6L)

**Camera2BasicFragment.java**

[Source](http://pastebin.com/Q8LMeCQR)

**AutoFitTextureView.java**

[Source](http://pastebin.com/38j7vzqb)

**fragment_camera2_basic.xml** (Make sure to replace com.YourPackage.AutoFitTextureView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
 Copyright 2014 The Android Open Source Project
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at
     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.YourPackage.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/containerFront"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Than in MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (null == savedInstanceState) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance())
                    .commit();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.containerFront, Camera2BasicFragmentFront.newInstance())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

And use this permission to **Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

That's all enjoy!

P.S
Java classes also contain method to save photo!

Comment: Can u give me complete source code? I'm just a beginner